File download fails between transfer
lately I'm encountering a weird issue with Sitecore 9.0.3.
When I try to download a PDF file from the server, the transfer fails somewhere in the middle.
It looks like a timeout.

I tried to download the file with WGET and I see that the transfer starts, but stops somewhere in the middle and fails after a minute or so. The transfer stops at different amount of bytes transfered.


Some other facts:

The file is successfully downloaded from CM node. It always fails to download it from CD nodes.
The file is published and visible in WEB database.
The file size does not matter, it fails for files from 20kB to 1.4MB.
The folder is published, since some other files in that folder are successfully downloaded. It also started to appear on multiple folders.
If I upload the file to another folder, sometimes it starts to work.
For some files I get error 500 page, but for some I just see a failed PDF viewer with the error message.

Has anyone had a similar issue?

If you paste the URL of the image directly into a browser, does it load the image?

It is a PDF file, and no, it fails also if I put the link directly to a new tab. It looks like all new files/images broke. Older files work normally.

Are your media blobs stored in the db or on the file system?

I think they are stored in DB.

Is it possible eother CM or CD is configured to use blob storage provider? Sounds like CM is storing them in a location that CD doesnt have access too (i.e. missing the configuration). Please look in the logs of the CD instance and paste (text not image) the exception that is logged at the same time as you failing to load the image.

Also, check this location on both CM and CD to see if any file exists: App_Config\Modules\Sitecore.AzureBlobStorage\Sitecore.AzureBlobStorage.config

It turned out that the disk was full on CD nodes.
The problem was MediaCache folder, and CD nodes could not transfer the files from DB to the content delivery disks.
After this folder was removed, all the files started to be served normally.
